# Adding partiitons to a table in GLue Catalog

Tags: hive, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog, hive-metastore

I have an external partitioned table defined in Glue catalog, with data stored in S3.

When I run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE {table}`, then I'm able to add partitions to the table and query it in Athena, as expected.

But when I add partition using boto3 APIs, then I get the following error ,when trying to query in Athena:

```
HIVE_UNKNOWN_ERROR: Can not create a Path from an empty string
```

I'm using the following code to add partitions:

```
partitions = {
    "Values": [
        "2020",
        "07",
        "01"
    ],
    "StorageDescriptor": {
        "Columns": [
            {
                "Name": "_hoodie_commit_time",
                "Type": "string"
            },
            {
                "Name": "_hoodie_commit_seqno",
                "Type": "string"
            },
            {
                "Name": "_hoodie_record_key",
                "Type": "string"
            },
            {
                "Name": "_hoodie_partition_path",
                "Type": "string"
            },
            {
                "Name": "_hoodie_file_name",
                "Type": "string"
            },
            {
                ...some more columns
            }
        ],
        "InputFormat": "org.apache.hudi.hadoop.HoodieParquetInputFormat",
        "OutputFormat": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat",
        "Compressed": False,
        "NumberOfBuckets": -1,
        "SerdeInfo": {
            "SerializationLibrary": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe",
            "Parameters": {
                "serialization.format": "1"
            }
        }
    }
}
glue_conn.create_partition(
    DatabaseName={database_name},
    TableName={table_name},
    PartitionInput=partitions
)
```

I also ran `describe formatted  test partition (year='2020', month='07', day='01');` and it looks exactly the same with the above two methods except for the `CreateTime` field:

```
# col_name              data_type               comment             
_hoodie_commit_time     string                                      
_hoodie_commit_seqno    string                                      
_hoodie_record_key      string                                      
_hoodie_partition_path  string                                      
_hoodie_file_name       string                                      
...some more columns
         
# Partition Information      
# col_name              data_type               comment             
year                    string                                      
month                   string                                      
day                     string                                      
         
# Detailed Partition Information         
Partition Value:        [2020, 07, 01]           
Database:               bidb                     
Table:                  test                     
CreateTime:             Tue Jan 12 12:08:44 UTC 2021     
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN                  
Location:               s3://location    
         
# Storage Information        
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe  
InputFormat:            org.apache.hudi.hadoop.HoodieParquetInputFormat  
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat   
Compressed:             No                       
Num Buckets:            -1                       
Bucket Columns:         []                       
Sort Columns:           []                       
Storage Desc Params:         
    serialization.format    1
```

Table definition:

```
hive> show create table static_portfolio;
OK
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `static_portfolio`(
  `_hoodie_commit_time` string, 
  `_hoodie_commit_seqno` string, 
  `_hoodie_record_key` string, 
  `_hoodie_partition_path` string, 
  `_hoodie_file_name` string, 
  ...some more columns)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `year` string, 
  `month` string, 
  `day` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hudi.hadoop.HoodieParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3:/location'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'bucketing_version'='2', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1610446119')
```

Comment: Why not call `MSCK REPAIR TABLE {table}` from the Athena boto3 API? Seems simpler and working.

Comment: It's a heavy operation. So, wouldn't want to do that for every partition added

Comment: And using ADD PARTITION? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-partition.html It is the traditional way of adding partitions to Hive/Glue tables.

Comment: @Gooseman Yes, I ended up doing that and it worked. But couldn't understand why the APIs don't work